# Authentification on Endpoints throws an InvocationTargetexception

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints

there.
I created an API with Google Cloud Engine that uses Firebase for the authentication. But always I make a call to this Api the response is:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
  {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
  }
],
"code": 400,
"message": "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
}
}
```

In the case I remove the parameter "User user", i get a 200-success response.

This is my code:

```
@Api(
    name = "crumb",
    version="v2",
    authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
    issuers = {
            @ApiIssuer(
                    name = "firebase",
                    issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/[Project-ID]",
                    jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    },
    issuerAudiences = {
            @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "[Project-ID]")
    }
)

public class crumbAPI {


   @ApiMethod(name = "getCrumbById",path = "{crumbId}",httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
   public Object getCrumbById(User user, @Named("crumbId") String crumbId) throws IOException, NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {

        if (user == null) {
              throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
        }

        CrumbInfo ci = CrumbInfo.entityToCrumb(crumbId);
        Bean response = new Bean();
        response.setData(ci);
        return response;

  }
}
```

I use this has a reference: [Authenticating Users](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users-frameworks)

Comment: Did you find the answer?